# getting attachments from a mailbox without the imap module

Tags: php, email, pop3

We want to implement a pop3 client that gets the attachments out of an email, checks if there are video files and save them. The problem is, we can't use the IMAP php module. So we need a custom pop3 class i guess.

Does anyone know a good pop3 client class that can handle attachments?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the pop3 class from phpclasses.